# Why did Yehuda/Shelah need Yibum with Tamar? She had a Chazaka

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, pentateuch-chumash, genesis-bereishith, parashat-vayeishev, yehuda

Why did Yehuda/Shelah have to Yibum, after all Tamar already has 2 of her husbands die, and even though we pasken chazakah happens after three times we pasken you only need 2 times for a danger?

Comment: This question would be a great deal more compelling if you'd [edit] in some context to provide foundation for the assertions the question is based on: 1) Yehuda/Shelah were obligated to do Yibum. 2) The obligation of Yibum is removed by a chazaka of husbands dying. 3) Two deaths constitutes a chazaka.

Answer (score 4):

The Ramban in chapter 38 verse 11 asks this question. It seems from his answer that Yehuda was aware of the cause of death of the two elder brothers. Yehuda assumed that he would wait till Sheila gets older and would be able to accept Yehuda’s mussar and then would be fitting for yibum.

Comment: Add the end of the day Yehuda said that Tamar was right and he should've done yibum.

Answer (score 2):

Many achronim say katlanis doesnt apply by yibum because shomer mitzva lo yada davar ra. The mitzva protects.